# Why is this Regex for integers not working?

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I wanted to make a regex to make sure the input is a valid integer. I wanted to avoid too, that people would input `001234` by unmatching leading zeroes. So my final solution is :

```
/^[^0][0-9]+$/
```

This works perfectly fine, but at first I also tried :

```
^[0-9]+(?<!^[0])$
```

Where I thought the negative look-behind would not match the wrong string but actually it does. I can input something like `00001` and it matches the whole word.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the second `^` should be in `[0]`

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/pqzeDo/2

Comment: The reason for the second question is: you are matching digits from 0-9 as many as possible and lookbehind *right at the end* - but there's a `1`. Go with @S.Kablar's approach.

Comment: do I understand you correctly - you have a working solution, but you'd like to know why your initial attempt did not work? If so, rephrase your question a little bit, it's easy to get the impression that you *don't* have a working solution.

Comment: Thanks to all for all your comments! Glad to see such a helpful community. I ended up using @Kyle Fairns solution /(?!^0)^[0-9]+$/  since as many pointed out my working solution was matching a1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(?!^0)^\d+$/
```

Makes sure that the first number isn't a 0 using a negative lookahead ([demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/r1CsvT/1))

Another option is to use this: ([demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/r1CsvT/2))

```
/^[1-9]\d+$/
```

Comment: Thanks to all for all your comments! Glad to see such a helpful community. I ended up using @Kyle Fairns solution /(?!^0)^[0-9]+$/  since as many pointed out my working solution was matching a1234

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** regex edited according to @WiktorStribiżew coments.

The first regex will match `a121312`, as `[^0]` matches any char but `0`.

If you want to use negative lookbehind, put it before the main group:`^(?!0)[0-9]+$`

To match valid integers you can use `^[1-9][0-9]*$`, see example: https://regex101.com/r/qjsA0G/1

Comment: It should be `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/` to allow 1-digit numbers. The `^(?<!0)[0-9]+$` must be `^(?!0)[0-9]+$`, the lookahead is required here, not a lookbehind.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew Fixing the part related to final regexp. 
You're right regarding to lookbehind/lookahea (I've tested it) I need to understand why it is like that - any tips?

Comment: `^(?<!0)[0-9]+$` = `^[0-9]+$` because there cannot be a `0` before the start of the string, that lookbehind always returns true and is redundant.

Comment: Ah, lookahead is relative to the character on it's left not on it's right. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: it doesn't matter where in the regex you place the lookahead or lookbehind. You could even place it in the middle of your main expression, provided that you don't interrupt the syntax (i.e. you can't place it in between a quantifier and what the quantifier refers to)

Comment: maybe you can add `|^0$` to match 0. But it doesn't explain why OP's regex is wrong

Comment: Thanks to all for all your comments! Glad to see such a helpful community. I ended up using @Kyle Fairns solution /(?!^0)^[0-9]+$/  since as many pointed out my working solution was matching a1234

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid zero at the beginning use `^(?!0)\d+$` otherwise use `^(?!0{n,})\d+$` where `n-1` is number of zeros allowed at the beginning of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pqzeDo/2)

Comment: Thanks to all for all your comments! Glad to see such a helpful community. I ended up using @Kyle Fairns solution /(?!^0)^[0-9]+$/  since as many pointed out my working solution was matching a1234

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, since you're matching `^[0-9]+etc`, the whole number will be matched, including leading zeros.

**Then, *after the whole number got matched*, the negative lookbehind checks whether there were any zeros before the match - which is not the case, since they're *part of the match*.**

Lookaheads only come into play *after* the rest of your regex has been applied. If their addition invalidates a found match, it is discarded, but they do **not** play any role in determining what is matched in the first place.

Therefore, just use the other regex you found (`/^[^0][0-9]+$/`) which apparently works as desired.

---

As mentioned by @mrzasa, your regex will also match leading letters, so using `^[1-9][0-9]*$` might work better for your purpose (unless you *want* letters, special signs, and basically any other unicode character - including whitespace - that is not `0`, to match).
Replacing the `+` with a `*` also allows 1-digit numbers (blatantly "stolen" advice from @Wiktor Stribiżew).

Comment: `/^[^0][0-9]+$/` matches `a123` that is invalid integer

Comment: not exactly the negative lookbehind is done from the right because it is placed after `[0-9]+`, so after `[0-9]+` has matched `001234` the `(?<!^0)` ensures current position in string (on the ritgh of `4`) is not preceeded by a `0` anchored to the start of string which is true because it's `4`.

Comment: Thanks to all for all your comments! Glad to see such a helpful community. I ended up using @Kyle Fairns solution /(?!^0)^[0-9]+$/  since as many pointed out my working solution was matching a1234

Comment: @MatiasBarrios I figured you were more interested in why your initial solution that involved negative lookbehind didn't work, which is what I focused on answering.

Comment: @PixelMaster Yes. thanks so much for your comment. It cleared the picture of why my first attempt did not work.